# Equations of motion of classical chromodynamics with Yang-Mills theory

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills, classical-field-theory, strong-force

I am currently reading a paper about classical chromodynamics: 
https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0607203

However I have problems understanding equation (2) and (4)

(2): 
\begin{equation}
F_{\mu \nu}= \partial _\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu - i g \left[A_\mu,A_\rho \right]. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Where $A_\mu = T_a A_\mu^a$ and $T_a$ is a basis of the corresponding Lie-algebra. So in case of the Lie-group $SU(3)$, $T_a$ could be the Gellmann-matrices. I can't see how the last index $\rho$ makes any sense, since it is no dummy index and does not appear on the left side. (might be a typo, i.e. $\rho \rightarrow \nu$?)

After plugging in this equation in the Yang-Mills equation of motion for $SU(3)$ and no quark sources: $\partial^\mu F_{\mu \nu} = -ig \left[A^\mu, F_{\mu \nu} \right]$, the paper obtains the result: 
\begin{equation}
\partial^\mu \left(\partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu - ig \left[A_\mu, A_\rho \right] \right) = -ig \left[A^\mu, \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu - ig \left[A_\mu, A_\rho \right] \right]ig \left[A_\mu, \left[A_\mu, A_\rho \right] \right]
\end{equation}
Assuming $\rho$ is actually $\nu$, where does the last term $ig \left[A_\mu, \left[A_\mu, A_\rho \right] \right]$ comes from.

The paper goes on to explore the special case $\left[A_\mu, A_\nu \right]=0$. It follows that 
\begin{equation}
\partial^\mu F_{\mu \nu} = 0 
\end{equation}
This identity requires the last term (as far as I was able to tell).

Any help whould be appriciated.

Comment: The indices in eq. (2) of the preprint is just a typo. Is it published somewhere?